# C - conditional jump (valgrind)

Tags: c, conditional-statements, valgrind

I don't understand condtional jump with valgrind, I made this little function but even if it-s small, there is this condtional jump

here's the function :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
char    *function(char *str)
{
  int   i = 0;
  int   a = 0;
  char  *cpy;

  cpy = malloc(100);
  while (str[i] != '\0')
    {
      if (str[i] == 'a')
        cpy[a++] = 'b';
      i++;
    }
  return (cpy);
}

int     main(int ac, char **av)
{
  char  *str;

  str = function(av[1]);
  printf("%s\n", str);
}
```

When i'm using valgrind like this

```
valgrind ./a.out "aa aa aaaaaaaaaaa"
```

it gives me 1 error

```
==3397== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==3397==    at 0x4C2E4E8: strlen (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3397==    by 0x4EA1531: puts (in /lib64/libc-2.24.so)
==3397==    by 0x400609: main (in /home/benoit.pingris/train/a.out)
```

What does it mean ?
Thanks.

Comment: "and I found that it was because I didn't initialize my variable" - so what is your question actually? Seems that you already found the reason.

Comment: I don't understand this error valgrind

Comment: Please show a [MCVE].

Comment: Is it better ? I'm sorry if it wasn't good before..

Comment: It's better, but your #includes of header files are still missing and we still don't know with which command line argument(s) you invoke the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it helps to compile your program with debugging symbols (use the `-g` option). This way, Valgrind is able to produce more helpful diagnostics.

The conditional jump does not occur inside your code, but rather happens when `printf()` is called at the end of `main()`. The reason for that is that you allocate the variable `cpy`, but this does not initialize its memory. Then, you are copying the character `'b'` into `cpy` for every `'a'` you see in `str`. However, you are not adding a NUL-terminator at the end of `cpy`. When you are trying to print `cpy`, something inside the C library will therefore read past the initialized part of `cpy`, triggering the error message from Valgrind.

Either add a NUL-terminator yourself (`cpy[a] = '\0';` before the `return`), or use `calloc()` instead of `malloc()`.